# How do I roll out a new version of a container in a pod on Kubernetes using Terraform?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, terraform

While I've been learning about Kubernetes and Terraform I've been building a Node.js microservices example.

It's all been going well so far and with a few commands I can provision a Kubernetes cluster and deploy a couple of Node.js microservices to it.

The full example is available on GitHub: https://github.com/ashleydavis/nodejs-microservices-example

You can see the full setup for the cluster and the pods in this file: https://github.com/ashleydavis/nodejs-microservices-example/blob/master/scripts/infrastructure/kubernetes/kubernetes.tf

For example one of the pods is defined like this:

```
resource "kubernetes_pod" "web" {
  metadata {
    name = "nodejs-micro-example-web"

    labels {
      name = "nodejs-micro-example-web"
    }
  }

  spec {
    container {
      image = "${var.docker_registry_name}.azurecr.io/web:${var.version}"
      name  = "nodejs-micro-example-web"
    }
  }
}
```

It all works great for the initial roll out, but I'm unable to get the system to update when I change the code and build new versions of the Docker images.

When I do this I update the variable "version" that you can see in that previous snippet of code.

When I subsequently run `terraform apply` it gives me the following error saying that the pod already exists:

```
kubernetes_pod.web: pods "nodejs-micro-example-web" already exists
```

**So my question** is how do I use Kubernetes and Terraform to roll out code updates (i.e. updated Docker images) and have new pods be deployed to the cluster? (and at the same time have the old pods be cleaned up).

Comment: I wanted to offer _my opinion_ that using terraform for that problem is a recipe for disaster, because now you have two systems each believing they own the state of the world. And when push comes to shove, kubernetes will win that fight because it is in charge of the state. Also, JFC, they can't even keep up with the AWS apis, which don't change at nearly the velocity k8s releases, so I wouldn't want to be waiting for some joker to update the terraform-kubernetes-provider to be able to author resources

Comment: Thanks a good point, thanks. Hopefully Terraform will catch up at some point.

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I've been using Terraform to manage my two microservices systems now for several weeks and it works fantastically so far. I've put Terraform in charge of managing Kubernetes so really I only have one system that is owning the state of the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question... I'm now using a Kubernetes deployment in my Terraform script to provision a pod and this works well.

[Full code example is on Github](https://github.com/ashleydavis/nodejs-microservices-example).

This is the configuration:

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "web" {
  metadata {
    name = "web"

    labels {
      test = "web"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels {
        test = "web"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels {
          test = "web"
    }
  }

  spec {
    container {
      image = "${var.docker_registry_name}.azurecr.io/web:${var.version}"
      name  = "web"

          port {
            container_port = 80
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the following line that is incorrect:

```
    name = "nodejs-micro-example-web"
```

because a Pod's name is unique within its namespace.

You almost **never** want to deploy a standalone Pod, because kubernetes considers those as ephemeral. That's ordinarily not a problem because Pods are created *under the supervision* of a `Deployment` or `ReplicationController` (or a few others, but you hopefully get the idea). In your case, if^H^H when that Pod falls over, kubernetes will not restart it and then it's a pretty good bet that outcome will negate a lot of the value kubernetes brings to the situation.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So should I include the version number in the name? I also gather I should be using a Kubernetes deployment so that's something I'll have to look into, although I'm trying to build the most basic Kubernetes cluster I can that's still a useful starting point for production - so I'll leave out the deployment if I can.

Comment: Do you think If use a Kubernetes 'deployment'on Terraform, will that work? https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/deployment.html

Comment: _Do you think If use a 'deployment' on Terraform, will that work?_ I do, yes, and that's the ideal outcome for that situation. The super weird part, as I mentioned in the other comment, is that kubernetes already has its own update and rollback mechanisms, and I shudder to think what's going to happen when it and terraform get into a fight about what state the deployment should be in. I sure do hope TF is adding enough value for the heartache it's causing

Comment: Ok so a deployment in Terraform seems to do the trick. I was able to deploy new docker images, update the version and run 'terraform apply' again to roll out the new code. The old deployment seems to get cleaned up automatically. Obviously there are more sophisticated production setups than this, but I gotta start somewhere ;) Thanks for your help.